# Медленно грузится windows

Tags: windows

В Windows 7 очень долго загружаются сетевые драйверы (наверное) то есть когда рабочий стол уже отобразился и можно даже зайти в папки, но другие элементы автозагрузки (например антивирь) ещё грузятся. В трее висит значок подключения к сети [image] минуты 4, и при этом всё жутко тормозит. Данная проблема у меня уже довольно давно. Кто сталкивался с этим, подскажите как решить. Или хотя бы подскажите как просмотреть протокол загрузки, чтобы знать какой именно элемент так долго грузится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Performance Toolkit из Windows SDK умеет показывать, что, как и сколько загружается.

Вот более-менее популярная статья на тему, как это посмотреть: [Ускорение загрузки Windows for fun and profit](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/windows/106684/).

Comment: прекрасная статья, очень помогла, хотя всё это довольно долго из-за сжатия файлов но результат уже на лицо - скорость загрузки возросла больше чем на порядок

Answer (score -2):

- Ищите твики, чистите реестр, оптимизируйте систему.
- Можете снести все нафиг и поставить заново.
- Или как я делаю - просто не выключайте комп и юзайте гибернейт

Comment: плохой ответ - твики редко когда помогают (нужен индивидуальный подход), реестр чистить можно до старости, систему снести - вообще бред - только школьники на это способны. Не выключать ноут я не могу так как в процессе работы часто требуется перезагрузка, гибернация аналогично

Comment: Твики - в Вин 7 не ня, чистка реестра - тем более. .з.

А вот гибернейт - это да, это тема =) Тоже перезагружаю только из-за обновлений.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я лучше знаю, я в этой теме уже давно. Я дал 3 варианта все из них работоспособны.

Comment: Не, это решения, но слишком кардинальные. Я так проблемы лет пять назад решать пытался, посему не впечатлён. Из той же темы - "тормозит - купите более мощный комп". Вот оптимизировать - это что надо - хотя бы с системного диска всякий хлам снести, дефрагментацию сделать, убрать лишнее из автозагрузки, что там не особо необходимо. Реестр на процесс загрузки влияет совсем не столько, сколько время доступа и чтения с диска.

Comment: Я же не предлагаю все сразу использовать) Это на выбор в зависимости от продвинутости человека и его лени. Некоторые вирусы в ручную отлавливают и чистят систему например.

Comment: Да кстати оптимизация в большинстве случаев и заключается в твиках.